# Create document in arangoDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, arangodb

what's the correct way to pass in json documents for creation ?

I have the example working and ok as below :
/* create a new document in collection */

```
db.document.create({a:"test"},function(err,ret){
if(err) console.log("error(%s): ", err,ret);
else console.log(util.inspect(ret));
});
```

but how do I pass in the json as an argument as this does not work ?

```
var json = '{a:"test"}';

db.document.create(json,function(err,ret){
if(err) console.log("error(%s): ", err,ret);
else console.log(util.inspect(ret));
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the "create" function from Kaerus repository above, the create function is:

```
"create": function() {
  var collection = db.name, data = {}, options = "", callback, i = 0;
  if(typeof arguments[i] === "boolean"){ 
    if(arguments[i++] === true)
      options = "&createCollection=true";
  } 
  if(typeof arguments[i] === "string") collection = arguments[i++];
  if(typeof arguments[i] === "object") data = arguments[i++];
  if(typeof arguments[i] === "function") callback = arguments[i++];
  return X.post(xpath+collection+options,data,callback);
},
```

So you either need to pass it as JavaScript object, that is call

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"test"}')
```

to convert a JSON representation to a JavaScript object or patch Kaerus client
to allow an object or string in the line

```
if(typeof arguments[i] === "object") data = arguments[i++];
```

(this might lead to problems with the optional arguments).

NOTE: In any case, it is important that "json" contains a valid JSON representation.

```
{ a: "Test" }
```

is not valid,

```
{ "a": "Test" }
```

is.

Comment: My data is in a stream so its a buffer. I converted that to a string and then did a JSON.parse on that. This doesn't work, I get back a '404' response. the JSON is valid (the output from a 'console.log' on the buffer tested here:http://jsonlint.com/). If I pass in the data directly it works fine...very confusing...

Comment: Ok, that is strange. 404 does not mean "corrupt JSON", but "collection not found". Can you try the following: db.document.create("COLLECTIONNAME",json,function(err,ret){
if(err) console.log("error(%s): ", err,ret);
else console.log(util.inspect(ret)); where COLLECTIONNAME is the name of the collection you are using?

Comment: I've tried than and the 404 error is fixed. its creating a document but without any of the passed in json data, i just have the _id, _key and_rev fields populated. the callback of the 'create' does not get called so there is no output from the 2 console lines.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this unit test: https://github.com/kaerus/arango-client/blob/master/test/api/document.js

Try

```
 var json = {"a":"test"};
```

Comment: Thankyou, I've had a brainstorm ! I'm calling the arango client function with stream data which will be a buffer and I've translated it to a string which is clearly not accepted, as per your comment. I guess what I need to know is how do I get from a string (or buffer) to the format you have suggested.

Comment: What about 

JSON.parse(yourJsonString);

?